# D3 line chart highlight specific linepath

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3 to plot a line graph. As part of customization, is there a way to highlight a specific line path as in below image on top of B4. Any tips are welcomed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cloning the existing path and customizing the path d attribute, stoke-width, color did the job.